# Is it possible to set project specific appearance settings in JetBrains PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I often work with several PhpStorm projects open at once in separate windows. This is because my company often builds projects from other projects, or combine multiple projects to make a new project.

One thing that has happened is that I have made edits accidentally to one project, not realizing it was the wrong project to edit.

I was wondering if there were any way of setting project level settings regarding the appearance of PhpStorm and other JetBrains IDEs. I love using JetBrains so it would be nice to have this feature, but it seems to only be an editor-level setting.

**For example, if I change to High Contrast, this makes all my projects High Contrast. I would like one project to be High Contrast while others to be a different theme, like IntelliJ light.**

[image: JetBrains Appearance Settings]

Comment: You cannot do that: GUI Theme is one for all opened projects.

Comment: You can: 1) have completely separate IDE settings (in other words: run 2 **independent** IDE instance where you will have **different** IDE settings. You basically need to run 2nd instance providing different paths to system folders: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#common-platform-properties

Comment: 2) You can create a Scope for all files in a project .. and then use different colors for each project. This way one project will have yellow background files, another blue one and 3rd one will have blue etc. Color affected areas: Project View panel, Editor tabs and some other file related places. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html#predefined-scopes-list

Comment: There is a related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130956